# Intercept XMLHttpRequest and send a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I am building a proxy for a video player which can intercept the http requests and send back the response using a Promise which can be resolved asynchronously

I have found this way of intercepting a http request

```
// save original `send` method
const origSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

// redefine `send` method
// you could also pass extra parameters if needed
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = (...origParams) => {
  console.log('send called');
  origSend(...origParams);
}
```

Now I don't want to return the response using origSend like in the above way.
What I need is to send the url to my backend engine which will download the content and send me the bytearray which I need to send back to the video player. To achieve this I was thinking of using a Promise which will be resolved by my backend engine when it is able to complete the request

Now what I am unsure is how to return the bytearray fetched by my engine back to the video player from the intercepted code. Would be great to find some relevant code snippets.

Comment: at first: dont try do modifiy the prototype of native browser code. It can break other stuff when other libriraries require that function. second: there a many libraries there that can do that stuff for you. like `axios`

Comment: So the video player is using XHR, and there's no other way to configure it to use a different source?

Comment: Can you not just check whether the `url` is that of the video, and if it is, redirect it to your own backend (by calling `oldXHROpen` with the proxy url)? Not sure what all of this has to do with promises.

Comment: If I am just logging the requests oldXHROpen would suffice to send a response. What I am looking at is handing over the request to my backend engine which will take care of downloading the content and sending the response. Once I get the response from the engine, I would want to send it back to video player. And all this has to happen asynchronously and for that I felt a Promise would be the best option.

Comment: Well I guess I need to intercept send and not open. I just edited the question.

Comment: Really hard to help without knowing what current process you are intercepting is. If library used isn't expecting a promise in `onreadystatechange` or other load listener can get complicated. Too many unknowns here

Comment: @charlietfl To explain a bit of what's happening, I am intercepting a request to download .ts file and will send across the request to my engine. The engine takes care of downloading the .ts file and sends me the bytearray which I want to send back as response.

Comment: What is request currently doing before you do this intercept? Bit confusing what you mean by engine also. Is that your server back end and it gets content from some other remote server?

Comment: @charlietfl What I am trying to build using this is a plugin to download a piece of file from multiple places, join it and send as response.


Without my plugin the entire file gets downloaded in entirety. Using my plugin I take control of any request in the page and download the content from multiple sources and send back the response.

So someone can use my javascript plugin and can start working seamlessly.

Comment: Is this working with  a specific player? Perhaps seeing the player methods would help. Still too many unknowns. Also if other code uses `fetch()` an XMLHttpRequest interceptor is useless

Comment: @charlietfl The main need for overriding the generic XMLHttpRequest is to make this agnostic to video player and not depend on video player methods since many video players are closed source.

The point you mentioned with being unable to catch a fetch request is a valid one but right now I am making an assumption most of the video players would be using XMLHttpRequest from whatever I have tested out.

Comment: At simplest level if all you are doing is returning same content format presumably all you would really need is to intercept the url and modify it to send to your proxy rather than original source. The rest of the request methods would work the same