# Send custom response to XMLHttpRequest by intercepting at client side

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

I want to build a javascript plugin which acts as a proxy and can intercept HTTP requests on the page and send a custom response for some of the requests while the remaining requests go uniterrupted.

My proxy should do something like this

```
if(request_url contains ".ts") {
    repondwith("customdata")
else {
    go uninterruped
}
```

What is the ideal way to approach this ?

I have looked at intercepting XMLHttpRequest but found no way to send a custom response

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.realSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
// here "this" points to the XMLHttpRequest Object.
var newSend = function(vData) { console.log("data: " + vData); this.realSend(vData); };
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = newSend;
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's a lot easier to work with newer API's like `fetch`. `fetch = function(...args){ return  Promise.resolve(new Response());`

Comment: The videojs video player http requests are not being caught by overwriting fetch API. This could be due to the video player using XMLHttpRequest internally and not fetch API

Comment: Client-side: use ```XMLHttpRequest``` or ```fetch``` to post data. Server.side: use PHP to retrieve data (e.g. ```$_POST```) and send custom response.

Comment: You already posted here a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864504/intercept-xmlhttprequest-and-send-a-promise

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner The idea is to intercept few of the GET requests and to send a custom response from the client side itself. Think of it like a proxy at the client side which is taking an intelligent decision everytime where to fetch the content from and is sending a custom response.

Comment: If so, you should elaborate your question. It's not clear (see Aluan Haddad's comment).

Comment: @AbsoluteBeginner I have replied to Aluan Haddad's comment too. The video players are not using fetch api, they are using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @Niharika "*Think of it like a proxy at the client side*" - why at the client side? You've already got your backend proxy that you call everytime anyway. There's absolutely no reason to make it that complicated by simulating a response.

Comment: @Niharika If you're really set out on implementing the proxy at the client side, have a look into service workers which can intercept arbitrary requests (not just xhr) and have proper functionality to "send" custom responses.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a lot for the response. I am trying out service workers but one problem I am seeing with service workers is the service worker code needs to be present in the folder where the html file is present and can't be loaded dynamically using a <script> tag. Ideally I want a plugin which acts like a proxy and can intelligently route requests and which don't have dependency of embedding the javascript file locally and can be loaded dynamically. Is there any possibility of registering a service worker dynamically from say an online url